# IPv6 6to4 on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, ipv6

I'm looking for a relatively simple guide to setting up an IPv6 tunnel properly.

This network currently has a server (Windows Server 2008R2) running RRAS that establishes connectivity to the internet using a demand-dial PPPoE connection and handles the NAT. It also hosts a DNS server and DHCP. My ISP does not support IPv6, but I have a static IPv4 address.

I've read about 6to4 and signed up at tunnelbroker.net, but quickly felt out of my depth. How do I configure my network to use it, and how I should configure my DHCP server with regards to IPv6 addresses?

Comment: Does your ISP even assign IPv6 IP addresses?  If they don't then what purpose is there to support them within your own home network?   **Do you have the required devices that support IPv6 most home routers sold in the last 3 years do not support it.**

Comment: Pretty sure this is mostly in the question, but no they don't hence the need for the tunnel, the purpose is more out of interest than need, but yes, all my kit does support IPv6 (RRAS on Windows Server IS the router)

Comment: @Ramhound: If the ISP doesn't assign IPv6 addresses, *the 6to4 tunnel will*.

Comment: Watch out that you don't confuse 6to4 with the 6in4 tunnels that Hurricane Electric (tunnelbroker.net) provides. 6to4 often causes more problems than it is worth. Tunnelbroker.net and other 6in4 tunnels are much more reliable. You can recognise 6to4 addresses because they start with 2002:  Avoid them :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot test with Server 2008, but the following should work:

To add a tunnel from command line, run `netsh` and type:

```
interface ipv6

add v6v4tunnel Tunnelbroker localaddr=<local_v4_address> remoteaddr=<tunnel_v4_endpoint>

add address Tunnelbroker address=<client_v6_endpoint>
add address Tunnelbroker address=<routed_prefix>:1 

add route ::/0               interface=Tunnelbroker            publish=yes
add route <routed_prefix>/64 interface="Local Area Connection" publish=yes

set interface Tunnelbroker            forwarding=enabled
set interface "Local Area Connection" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled
```

Replace `<local_address>` with the server's IPv4 address (the external one in your case with PPPoE, internal if the server itself is behind a NAT).

Replace `<tunnel_endpoint>` with the IPv4 address of your tunnel's server endpoint (given in the Tunnelbroker tunnel info page).

Replace `<prefix>` with your tunnel's IPv6 "Routed /64" prefix, for example, `2001:470:1f0b:614::` (given in the tunnel info page).

---

This only configures IPv6 Stateless Autoconfiguration. After the tunnel is created (the first 3 commands might be enough), you should be able to create DHCPv6 scopes in the DHCP management console. Someone who can test it on Server 2008 should expand this part...